# button "submit" inside a partial view

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I don't find how to submit a form that's in a partial view.

I've made a kind of search engine for a website. I'd like to add it in the layout from a partial view. My problem is that when I click on 'submit', nothing happens if I'm not in the search view.

Here is the code of the partial view

```
@Using Html.BeginForm(IsPost)
    @Html.TextBox("SearchString") 
   @<input type="submit" value="Go!"/>
End Using
```

How should I parameter my button if I want it to work correctly?

```
Namespace MvcApplication4
Public Class SearchController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Private db As schema_crmEntities = New schema_crmEntities
'
' GET: /Search
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View()
    End Function

    '
    ' POST: /Search
    <HttpPost()>
    Function Index(search As String) As ActionResult
        Dim chaine As String = Request("searchString")

    [...]
        Dim model = New SearchModel With {
            .Meetings = meetings,
            .Interviews = interviews,
            .Opportunites = opportunites,
            .Clients = clients,
            .Contacts = contacts
            }

        Return View(model)
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

;

```
  <form method="post" action="/(S(v1sax2fo0frbeuw1ul1xcoet))/Search"><input type="text" value="" name="SearchString" id="SearchString"/>            

   <input type="submit" value="Go!"/>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you specify the controller and the action you are posting to:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post)
    @Html.TextBox("SearchString") 
    @<input type="submit" value="Go!"/>
End Using
```

Comment: @Using Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search") or Using Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", IsPost) redirect me to the gat-index action.

Comment: @patxy, what is the `IsPost` variable? Where does it come from? What's its type? If you have specified a GET verb it's normal that it will redirect you to the Index action. You should specify POST verb. I have update my answer to illustrate how to do this.

Comment: I need to write "IsPost" inside the () of the beginform, however, it does always redirect me to the get. It's not a type, I think it's just a parameter that I have to add to the forms.

Comment: @patxy, is it a variable you have declared somewhere? Did you see my updated answer and the usage of `FormMethod.Post` as third parameter?

Comment: I think that FormMethod.Post does exactly the same as "IsPost". Because I haven't declared it anywhere. I found it with a piece of chance while I was dealing with the same kind of problem. FormMethod.Post hasn't solved the problem. I'll edit my question with the controller code within a few seconds

Comment: @patxy, not at all. IsPost is a boolean variable whose value will be false in this case. Could you show the generated `<form>` element in the resulting HTML? It should look like this: `<form action="/search/index" method="post">`. Is it the case? Also did you try `@Using Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post)`?

Comment: @patxy, WOW, what's this `/(S(v1sax2fo0frbeuw1ul1xcoet))`? You have activated cookieless sessions in your web.config - `<sessionState cookieless="true" />`? Don't do that. This doesn't work well with ASP.NET MVC as it will completely mess up your routes.

Comment: I've not done this by purpose. Do I just have to do put this <sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false" customProvider="MySqlSessionStateProvider"> becoming <sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" customProvider="MySqlSessionStateProvider">  ??? By doing this, it removes the (v1sax2fo0frbeuw1ul1xcoet) from the url, but I still don't go to the post verb

Comment: You should replace `cookieless="true"` with `cookieless="UseCookies"` in your web.config.

Comment: Ok, I'd made a stupid mistake. I was going to the controller, but the way I had made a mistake in my view :-(. So the things that I had to display weren't. And I though the problem was from the controller. Thx a lot both of you!

Answer (score 2):

You want to change the overload of Html.BeginForm like this:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post)
```

---

UPDATE:

It look like that the problem is related to cookieless session being enabled in web.config which prepends the `(S(v1sax2fo0frbeuw1ul1xcoet))` string to the url.

Comment: Ok, I'd made a stupid mistake. I was going to the controller, but the way I had made a mistake in my view :-(. So the things that I had to display weren't. And I though the problem was from the controller. Thx a lot both of you!

Comment: Thanks for the update both of you. I'm glad you got it sorted eventually!